# Opening AFOpenFlowView already in landscape mode

Tags: iphone

I'm using the open source CoverFlow replacement from here: http://fajkowski.com/blog/2009/08/02/openflow-a-coverflow-api-replacement-for-the-iphone/

When I detect that a certain view has gone from portrait to landscape mode, I instantiate an AFCoverFlowView and push it onto the navigation stack.

If I do so in response to

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation

The cover flow view comes up as though the phone were still in portrait mode.

If I push the view in response to

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation

it works perfectly - the view comes up in landscape mode with the phone in landscape mode

Unfortunately, the device doesn't reliable get willRotateToInterfaceOrientation messages.  I have tried making sure that

[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

is in loadView but that doesn't help with the notificiations.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there a way to reliably get willRotateToInterfactOrientation?

if not

2. How do I instruct AFCoverFlowView to come up in landscape mode (if the device is already in landscape mode)

Answer (score 2):

I did a transformation on the flowView from the controller class like this:

```
    CGAffineTransform transform = self.view.transform;
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, (M_PI / 2.0));
self.view.transform = transform;
```

Which worked well enough for my purposes.